# Access GUI of an already running application through SSH

Tags: ssh, x11, gnu-screen

I have a virtual server, and a graphic application (an electron browser, actually) is running on it.

I actually run the command launching it with this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -e

# Start Xvfb
Xvfb -ac -screen scrn 1280x800x24 :9.0 &
export DISPLAY=:9.0

exec "$@"
```

It's running even while I'm not connected to ssh, in a `screen`. However sometimes when connecting to the server I want to access its GUI. It's different from launching it directly with `ssh -X`. Is there any way to access the display created by Xfvb?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can start a VNC server on an existing X server by using x11vnc. However, if you anticipate the need to do this, you may want to use Xvnc instead of Xvfb.

Comment: Thank you. By running `x11vnc -display :9' on the server and putting the ip of the server into a vnc viewer, I'm able to access the display.